# Using JavaScript to step through a CSV

Tags: php, javascript, html, csv

So I have a csv file as follows

```
Name1,url1
Name2,url2
Name3,url3
```

I would like to create a javascript(can also use PHP if needed) to go through each line of the csv, and compare the Name, to the website. The picture the page being top left quadrant just a box that shows the "name", the right half of the page loads the url and the bottom left guadrant has a left and right arrow that you can click to move through the CSV.

I am considering iFrames to breakup the page. The real challenge is loading in the CSV. I was considering doing this with php, and placing all the data into the html page, but if my CSV is large this might be a problem.

Am I going about this problem in the correct way?

Comment: What are you really asking here, can you distill it down a bit?  Like, "how can I load a CSV file so that I can examine it with JavaScript?". As it stands, your question is very broad in scope.

Comment: I have a bunch of names of places, and urls that go along with them. I have over 10,000 I have to go through and visually inspect that each one is correct. So I am trying to create a javascript page that will make this easier

Comment: Can you show an example (in text form, or using jsfiddle.net) what you expect to have from a line "name,www.name.com" ?

Comment: Using frames is never the correct way, it may be the only way in some cases, but it's not the correct way.

Comment: Your question is asking how to implement something which is not a good fit for SO. SO is for "Here's my code, it should do A but it's doing B when I do X,Y,Z".

Comment: If I shouldn't use frames to load the url into a section of my page what should I use instead?

Comment: Grzegorz - I want my "Name" field just simply printed out and I have code to do that. But I want to url louded in a frame, and then a button that i can click to move to the next name and load the next url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something like this once before. Made an AJAX call to get the CSV (using jQuery):

```
var x = $.ajax('schedule.csv').done( function(){parse(x);});
```

Then parsed the data like this:

```
function parse (data)
{
    cells=[];
    rowBreaks = [];
    rowCounter=0;
    var cellCounter=0;
    var inQuotes = false;

    y=data.responseText;
    console.log(y.length);
    for(n=0; n<y.length; n++)
    {
        if(n == 0 & y[n] != ",")
            cells[cellCounter]=y[n];
        if(n != 0 && y[n] != ',')
        {
            cells[cellCounter]+=y[n];
        }
        if(y[n] == '"')
            inQuotes = !inQuotes;
        if(n>0 && !inQuotes && y[n] == ",")
        {
            if(cells[cellCounter] == undefined)
                cells[cellCounter] = " ";
            else
                cells[cellCounter]+=" ";
            cellCounter++;
        }
        if(n>0 && !inQuotes && (y[n] == "\n" || y[n] == "\r"))
        {
            rowBreaks[rowCounter] = cellCounter;
            rowCounter++;
        }
        if(cells[cellCounter] == undefined)
            cells[cellCounter] = "";
    }
    fixRows();
    writeTable();
    $("body").css("overflow-x", "auto");

}
```

You shouldn't need all that, but it'll parse a CSV file pretty handy. If it helps, the `writeTable()` function looked like this:

```
function writeTable()
{
    table=$("<table border='1' cellpadding='1' />");
    var q;
    var rowBlank;
    var rowLength = rowBreaks[0]-8;
    for(z=0; z<rowBreaks.length; z++)    
    {
        tr = $("<tr />");
        if(z == 0)
            tr.addClass("header");
        rowBlank = true;
        for(i=0; i<rowLength; i++)
        {
            q=(z)*25+i;
            td=$("<td />").html(cells[q]);
            tr.append(td);
            if(cells[q] != " " && cells[q] != "" && cells[q] != "\n" && cells[q] != "\r")
                rowBlank = false;
        }
        /*if(!rowBlank)*/
        table.append(tr);
    }

    table.css({
        "border-spacing"    : 0,
        "width"             : "100%",
        "height"            : "99%"

    });

    $("#schedule").html("");
    $("#schedule").append(table);
    sizeTable();
}
```

It's ugly, but it worked for me.

Note, this is all real code, so you don't need the `console.log()`'s I used for debugging, or to keep any of the variable names. This was used to parse an 80 x 20 excel sheet saved as an excel file before I got the company to switch to Google Docs, so it's pretty robust in terms of size of CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you will want to use [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

```
<?php
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        list($name, $url) = $data;
        // do something with $name and $data
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Just bear in mind a few things:

- If this file needs to be read frequently you're going to run into I/O problems.
- If this file needs to be *written to* frequently you're going to run into I/O problems much more quickly.
- Try not to store any more than the bear minimum of rows in memory, otherwise you may bump up against PHP's memory limits.
- CSV bad, database good.

Comment: So instead of storing my raw data in an CSV, you think I should use a database to store the data instead? If so then I would place my data in an MySQL(My prefered database, feedback welcome if you feel otherwise), and use php/javascript to connect to that database and load the data?

Comment: @djc391 In the majority of cases it would be better to store large quantities of data like this in a SQL database. Immediate benefits would be things like indexing, query caching, more fluid integration with other data [other tables], as well as being able to offload data operations to another server.